# OBShapedButton class in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nib, obshapedbutton

I am trying to implement the OBShapedButton class in my iOS project so I can create irregular shaped buttons defined by png files. This is a [link](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) for more information on OBShapedButton.

Basically this class works great when I'm using it with my nib files. However I prefer using storyboard in my projects. But when I try to do the same thing in storyboard, following all the same steps for making an irregular button as I do in my nib files, it doesn't work and the clickable area is still defined by a rectangle and not my png image.

My question is how would I go about using storyboard with OBShapedButton? Is there something I am missing about storyboard that would prevent OBShapedButton from working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it in a project with Storyboards. Be sure the set the Custom Class in the Identity inspector to `OBShapedButton`, I don't think I did anything else special.